# Can't find why do I have a null reference exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception, nullreferenceexception

Below is the code and the problematic line.

When I hover with the mouse on `src.EnergyServiceLevel`, it shows that it's null.
How can that be if I'm checking for null in the previous line?

My guess was that maybe there are threads that making the problem so I've add a lock,
but it didn't helped.

```
public static ServiceLevelsGroup SafeClone(this ServiceLevelsGroup src) {
  ServiceLevelsGroup res = null;
  lock (_locker) {
    if (src != null) {
      res = new ServiceLevelsGroup();
      if (src.EnergyServiceLevel != null) {
        res.EnergyServiceLevel = new ServiceLevelInfo { ServiceGrade = src.EnergyServiceLevel.ServiceGrade };

        if (src.EnergyServiceLevel.Reason != null)
          res.EnergyServiceLevel.Reason = src.EnergyServiceLevel.Reason;
      }
    }
  }

  return res;
}
```

The exception occurs at the `res.EnergyServiceLevel = ...` line in the above code.

Here's a screenshot of the exception occurring in debug mode:

[image: Screenshot of exception while debugging]

Comment: Could you copy the code into your post instead of posting an image? The text is too small to read.

Comment: Please post the exception details as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: I'm guessing that, since this is an extension method, that `ServiceLevelsGroup`/`ServiceLevelInfo` aren't classes in your control? In which case, the exception might be coming from within the `ServiceLevelInfo` constructor - what happens if you open the "View Detail..." link, and drill into appropriate `InnerException`s?

Comment: @hammar: you can watch the image directly to have a full-scale view.

Comment: @MainMa: Yes, but it's still better to post it in text as it's easier for people to help and it also indexes better in search engines later on.

Comment: Are you sure you are using debuger correclty?

Comment: Is EnergyServiceLevel a property?  The getter might have a side-effect that is triggered by your debug mouse-over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code shows `lock(_locker)` - so it looks like you're in a multithreaded environment. Can you check that nothing else is NULLing your variable? i.e. that everything else is also calling `lock(_locker)` correctly?

Comment: +1 A lock is only useful if you lock the setter as well. Although, since the OP is defining an extension method, he/she probably doesn't have access to the original code.

Comment: I think you're the closest to the real thing, once i get to worl again i'll check maybe I didn't lock properly in other parts of the code.

Comment: thanks - if it's not a locking issue, then do use "view detail" and take a look at the call stack for the exception - it might just be somewhere inside the evaluation of the property.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your NULL is at `res.EnergyServiceLevel`.

Comment: This wouldn't cause a NullReferenceException

Answer (score 0):

`src.EnergyServiceLevel.ServiceGrade` may be null

Moving mouse pointer to each reference will exactly show you which is null.

Comment: This wouldn't cause a NullReferenceException

Comment: *assigning* a `null` value is perfectly legal